# VBA code solution does not work as required

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I want results as I mark yellow in the screenshot below. Maybe there is the best solution because I tried not to succeed.
There may be the best recommendation solution.
so the code I use doesn't have any results

```
SHEET : DBMASTER
CODE    DESCRIPTION    PRICE1   UNIT    PRICE2  UNIT2
1000    BAG R 1000 NEW  10000   YARD    15000   MTR
1001    BAG R 1001 NEW  20000   YARD    25000   MTR
1002    BAG R 1002 NEW  25000   YARD    30000   MTR
```

```
SHEET : DATADB
INV    CODE  DESCRIPTION    QTY UNIT1   REMARK             PRICE1
01-001  1000                10          READY IN BRANCH 01  
01-002  1002                15          READY IN BRANCH 01  
01-003  1000                25          READY IN BRANCH 02  
01-004  1001                12          READY IN BRANCH 03  
01-005  1000                13          READY IN BRANCH 04
```

```
OUTPUT DESIRED RESULT SHEET : DATADB
INV     CODE    DESCRIPTION     QTY UNIT1   REMARK              PRICE1
01-001  1000    BAG R 1000 NEW  10  YARD    READY IN BRANCH 01  15000
01-002  1002    BAG R 1002 NEW  15  YARD    READY IN BRANCH 01  30000
01-003  1000    BAG R 1000 NEW  25  YARD    READY IN BRANCH 02  15000
01-004  1001    BAG R 1001 NEW  12  YARD    READY IN BRANCH 03  25000
01-005  1000    BAG R 1000 NEW  13  YARD    READY IN BRANCH 04  15000
```

```
Sub trial()
Dim Rng As Range, Ds As Range, n As Long, Dic As Object, Source As Variant
Dim Ary As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("DBMASTER")
    Source = .Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Offset(, 0).Resize(, 6)
End With
Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dic.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
For n = 2 To UBound(Source, 1)
    Dic(Source(n, 1)) = n
Next
With Sheets("DATADB")
    Ary = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value2
'update code
    ReDim Nary(1 To UBound(Ary), 1 To 5)
    For n = 1 To UBound(Ary)
         If Dic.Exists(Ary(n, 1)) Then
            Nary(n, 1) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 2)
            Nary(n, 3) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 4)
            Nary(n, 5) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 3)
            End If
    Next n
 .Range("C2").Resize(UBound(Nary), 5).Value = Nary
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

[image: RESULT25052022]
[image: debugcode]
[image: result]

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Your post does not contain a question (see [ask]). Please include what is wrong with your code, explain what your code should do, show how your desired result would look like. Tell which errors you get or what your code does versus what you expect it to do. • Note that writing in capital letters is unfriendly and considered screaming. Please change it.

Comment: What is your code doing? Have you debugged it to see where it fails? Any reason you don't use a simple VLookup?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ , sorry if I am not good at asking questions and I have added a problem comment in the code

Comment: @FunThomas , my code does the same as the vlookup function. I have debugged and also I attach the screenshot and I do not use the standard "vlookup" because for perfomance very fast using vba array and dictionary

Comment: @Jack Did you debug your code? Go through your code using F8 and see which steps are executed. Check the variable content in each step to find out where it goes wrong.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ , okay I've done as screenshot i attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `CStr(Ary(n, 1))` with `Ary(n, 1)`

The items in your dictionary are of type `Double` (see image below):
[image]

But you check for existance of a `String` when you use `Dic.Exists(CStr(Ary(n, 1)))`. Therefore you need to remove `CStr`.

*I doubt that VBA is faster than a VLOOKUP formula in the cell. Note that VBA cannot use multi-threading and therefore can only use one thread/core of your processor. Fomulas in cells do not have this limitation, and therefore are usually faster. I recommed to test it with a huge bunch of data which one really is faster.*

---

In your code the issue is that you have empty columns in your array `Nary` so you overwrite the existing values with the empty ones from the array:

[image]

The columns 2 and 4 in the array say `Leer` which means `Empty`.

To avoid that replace

```
ReDim Nary(1 To UBound(Ary), 1 To 5)
```

with

```
Dim Nary() As Variant
Nary = .Range("C2").Resize(UBound(Ary), 5).Value2
```

to load the original data into your array `Nary` before you fill in new data. So right after that line above your array looks like this:

[image]

And now the columns 2 and 4 are already pre-filled with the existing data, and your loop fills just the rest (column 1, 3 and 5).

In the end all 5 columns are filled and can be written into the cells:
[image]

---

I would write the code like below:

```
Public Sub FillData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DBMASTER")
        Dim Source() As Variant
        Source = .Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Offset(, 0).Resize(, 6).Value2
    End With
    
    Dim Dic As Object
    Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 2 To UBound(Source, 1)
        Dic(Source(n, 1)) = n
    Next n
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATADB")
        Dim Ary() As Variant
        Ary = .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
        
        Dim DataRange As Range
        Set DataRange = .Range("C2").Resize(UBound(Ary), 5)
        
        Dim Nary() As Variant  ' read existing data
        Nary = DataRange.Value2
        
        For n = 1 To UBound(Ary)
             If Dic.Exists(Ary(n, 1)) Then
                Nary(n, 1) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 2)
                Nary(n, 3) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 4)
                Nary(n, 5) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 3)
            End If
        Next n
        
        DataRange.Value2 = Nary
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's correct that formulas may  be faster (not much faster), but they increase the workbook size (for a huge bunch of data) and may be a pain in the ass for some small operations which trigger `Calculation` event. Ranges copying/deletion/inserting, for instance and not only...

Comment: @FaneDuru Well, then I would still test if, writing the formula with VBA and then replacing the values `.Value = .Value` makes a difference. And if there is no big difference then writing a code for putting the formula is a 3 liner while doing the stuff with VBA is very likely not.

Comment: It may be a way. But three such `Vlookup`, each for the necessary columns to be filled are necessary. Working only in memory and using two iterations I think may be comparable fast. `Evaluate` may be used, too, but it will not increase the speed, I am afraid. I know how to return for a column at once (2D array), I know how to return for a row (using `{2,4,6]` (1D array), but I never was able to combine the two ways in order to return a 2D array containing more than a column. At once, I mean...

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ,thanks for the reply from you. I have tried your advice to run perfectly but there is a little problem you can see the code update and screenshot

Comment: @Pᴇʜ , so that the data record in column d,f becomes lost if I run the code

Comment: @Jack see my edit. You need to load the existing data into your array first, then fill the missing columns with data and then write it back.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ , the solution code from you runs very perfectly

Comment: @Pᴇʜ , I have a little problem if in column F contains a formula then if I run the code from you then it becomes value whether there is a solution for column f remains a formula

Comment: @Pᴇʜ , and also if the code I make delete or I make blank then I run the code from you should column C,E,G be blank but there is still a result of the previous code

Comment: @Jack Please open up a new question for that, I cannot answer that in comments. Start a new question and show what exactly you did, showing example input and output data and describe what exactly the issue is.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ , okay here's my latest post link  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72477320/vba-code-solution-does-not-work-as-required-2

Answer (score 2):

Please, test the next updated code. It will return starting from "I1". If the return is OK(what you need), you may overwrite the initial range (dropping the result in "A1"):

```
Sub trial()
 Dim n As Long, Dic As Object, Source, Ary

 With Sheets("DBMASTER")
    Source = .Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Offset(, 0).Resize(, 6)
 End With
 Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
 Dic.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
 For n = 2 To UBound(Source, 1) 'place the necessary data in the a dict item array
    Dic(Source(n, 1)) = Array(Source(n, 2), Source(n, 4), Source(n, 5))
 Next

 With Sheets("DATADB")
    Ary = .Range("A1:G" & .Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    For n = 2 To UBound(Ary)
        If Dic.Exists(Ary(n, 2)) Then
            Ary(n, 3) = Dic(Ary(n, 2))(0)
            Ary(n, 5) = Dic(Ary(n, 2))(1)
            Ary(n, 7) = Dic(Ary(n, 2))(2)
        End If
    Next n
    .Range("I1").Resize(UBound(Ary), UBound(Ary, 2)).value2 = Ary
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the reply from you. I've tried to run perfectly But I want to just fill in the C,E and G columns

Comment: @Jack But this is what the above dode does... Did you read the sentence before the code? I told you that it returns "I1" for testing reasons. If you want it to return in C, E and G, please do what I said: **In the last code line replace "I1" with "A1"**...

Comment: @FameDuru , Thank you for the reply from you went perfectly. If you see from the code I updated the post and screenshot why my code eliminates the data record in columns d & f

Comment: @Jack What do you mean by columns elimination? **Does the above code eliminate any column**? Are you asking about your code? If so, how to have data in those columns if your code **does  not write anything there**?

Comment: I mean my code. My code is already running you can update in my code but omit the contents of the data in the D & F column when running my code

Comment: @Jack Using a second array (`Nary`) is not only unnecessary/useless, when `ReDim` it, **it is empty** and you load only three columns. If you make the iteration on `Ary`, this one is already loaded and you only **change its columns values**...

Comment: can you give additional answers from my code ?

Comment: @FaneDuru Just out of interest: What do you mean by your comment to PEH's answer *" I never was able to combine the two ways [=array column|row slice] in order to return a 2D array containing more than a column... At once"*, possibly you want to ask this as own question.

Comment: @FaneDuru , Now that I ask you a solution for my code, do you have any other solutions?

Comment: @Jack We here do not play with solutions. I answer your question adapting the code to return in the way you need...

Comment: @FaneDuru , functionally generate what I want but is different from the answer '@PEH' who seeks or memodicates code from me

Comment: @T.M. I meant that I can obtain a 2D array using `arrV = Application.Vlookup(rngLookup, rngTbArr, 2, False)`. I was trying `arrV = Application.Vlookup(rngLookup, rngTbArr, Array(2, 4, 6), False)`, hoping to receive a 2D array returning on columns each `Vlookup` match. It does not raise an error, but still returns only in a column (for first array el: 2).  I can also obtain a 1D array using `arr = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(B2," & rngTbArr.Address(external:=True) & ",{2,4,6},FALSE)")`. It returns a 1D array for the three tested array columns.

Comment: @T.M. `arr = = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(" & rngLookup.Address & "," & rngTbArr.Address(external:=True) & ",{2,4,6},FALSE)")` returns the same 1D array for the three tested array columns. Nothing in terms of rows, as I expected...

Comment: @Jack I cannot get you. I would say, it is a matter of choice...

Comment: @FaneDuru What about `=INDEX(DBMaster!A2:G4,MATCH(B2:B6,DBMaster!A2:A4,0),{2,7,4,7,3}) where `7` references column G thus showing empty columns after (2) `Description` and (4)`Unit` ?
`

Comment: @T.M. It returns interesting in a cell, but I cannot evaluate it to an array. It only returns the first occurrence, in terms of rows and columns. It does even not return an array... Only  "BAG R 1000 NEW".

Comment: The *tabular* function spills as desired, whereas `Evaluate` does indeed appear to be *limited*. - 
Using VBA you might provide first for an array of found row indices via
 `RowsArr = Application.Match(codes.Value2, src.Resize(, 1).Value2, 0)` and assign
the lookup values to 2D-array `results` via  
 `results = Application.Index(src.Value2, RowsArr, Array(2, 7, 4, 7, 3))`,
where `codes` references `B2:B6` in DataDB, `src` all data in DBMaster. - Eventually there remain only *two* empty array columns to be filled (instead of three single loops) allowing to write back `results` in one go.

Comment: @FaneDuru Remains the question if this behaviour shoult be qualified as a bug, or more precisely where are the actual limits of `Evaluate`. Possibly worth a question?

Comment: @T.M. It may be interesting to debate this aspect but now I am involved in another project and I like to document well an eventual question. No time in this period for such an issue... :) From VBA point of view I am now interested in the VBA/Excel limitations for maximum areas/cells of a discontinuous range to deleted. I knew only about such a (cells/areas) limitation in version before 2007, inclusively, but it looks the newer versions have such a limitation, too, even if it looks to be bigger than 8192 different areas in 16384 cells, in case of 2007. No enough time for that, too...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245081/discussion-between-t-m-and-faneduru).