# VBA code solution does not work as required 2

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

the vba code issue below is as follows :

1 for the column "QTY" contains a formula i.e. multiplication of the QTY1 column by the QTY2 column If I run the vba then the column "QTY" being the value should still contain the formula

2 if I use that vba in the "CODE" column I omit any of the values in the column then it should be the result of vba making blank but the result of the previous vba process is still there

3 i use a macro shortcut which is "CTR+SHIFT+S" whether the shortcut can run the vba code only on the active sheet that i use

thanks
jack

```
Public Sub FillData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DBMASTER")
        Dim Source() As Variant
        Source = .Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Offset(, 0).Resize(, 6).Value2
    End With
    
    Dim Dic As Object
    Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 2 To UBound(Source, 1)
        Dic(Source(n, 1)) = n
    Next n
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATADB")
        Dim Ary() As Variant
        Ary = .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
        
        Dim DataRange As Range
        Set DataRange = .Range("C2").Resize(UBound(Ary), 5)
        
        Dim Nary() As Variant  ' read existing data
        Nary = DataRange.Value2
        
        For n = 1 To UBound(Ary)
             If Dic.Exists(Ary(n, 1)) Then
                Nary(n, 1) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 2)
                Nary(n, 3) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 4)
                Nary(n, 5) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 3)
            End If
        Next n
        
        DataRange.Value2 = Nary
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

```
sheet : DATADB
INV    CODE     DESCRIPTION     QTY UNIT1   REMARK             PRICE1   QTY2    QTY3
01-001  1000    BAG R 1000 NEW  100 YARD    READY IN BRANCH 01  10000   10       10
01-002  1002    BAG R 1002 NEW  225 YARD    READY IN BRANCH 01  25000   15       15
01-003  1000    BAG R 1000 NEW  625 YARD    READY IN BRANCH 02  10000   25       25
01-004  1001    BAG R 1001 NEW  144 YARD    READY IN BRANCH 03  20000   12       12
01-005  1000    BAG R 1000 NEW  169 YARD    READY IN BRANCH 04  10000   13       13
```

```
sheet : DBMASTER
CODE    DESCRIPTION     PRICE1  UNIT1   PRICE2  UNIT2
1000    BAG R 1000 NEW  10000   YARD    15000   MTR
1001    BAG R 1001 NEW  20000   YARD    25000   MTR
1002    BAG R 1002 NEW  25000   YARD    30000   MTR
```

[image: shortcut key]
[image: result excel]
[image: result gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 options either re-write the formula.

Or handle each column on its own instead of the entiere data range. So instead of one `DataRange` that spans over the columns you don't want to change you need to have multiple data ranges (in your case 3):

Something like below could work. But I have not tested it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FillData()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DBMASTER")
        Dim Source() As Variant
        Source = .Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Offset(, 0).Resize(, 6).Value2
    End With
    
    Dim Dic As Object
    Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 2 To UBound(Source, 1)
        Dic(Source(n, 1)) = n
    Next n
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATADB")
        Dim Ary() As Variant
        Ary = .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
        
        Dim DataRange(1 To 3) As Range
        Set DataRange(1) = .Range("C2").Resize(UBound(Ary), 1)
        Set DataRange(2) = .Range("E2").Resize(UBound(Ary), 1)
        Set DataRange(3) = .Range("G2").Resize(UBound(Ary), 1)
        
        ReDim Nary(LBound(DataRange) To UBound(DataRange)) As Variant
        For n = LBound(DataRange) To UBound(DataRange)
            Nary(n) = DataRange(n).Value2  'read values of 3 dataranges
        Next n
        
        If Ary(n, 1) = vbNullString Then  ' if code is empty
            ' blank values in C, E and G too
            Nary(1)(n, 1) = vbNullString 
            Nary(2)(n, 1) = vbNullString 
            Nary(3)(n, 1) = vbNullString 
        Else
            For n = 1 To UBound(Ary)
                If Dic.Exists(Ary(n, 1)) Then
                    Nary(1)(n, 1) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 2)
                    Nary(2)(n, 1) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 4)
                    Nary(3)(n, 1) = Source(Dic(Ary(n, 1)), 3)
                End If
            Next n
        End If
        
        For n = LBound(DataRange) To UBound(DataRange)
            DataRange(n).Value2 = Nary(n) ' write data back to 3 dataranges
        Next n
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @PEH , Thank you reply from you it went perfectly for the first choice and for the second option on I omitted or blanked one of the values in the "CODE" column then I ran the code for column C,E,G there remains the previous output result even though in the "CODE" column it is empty

Comment: @Jack then you would need to check if code is blank and blank your values too. See my edit.

Comment: @PEH , Thank you reply from you. I tried an additional code edit from you but it's still the same. if first in the "code" column contains the value I continue to run the code then the c,e,g column will be filled in then if I omit it or I make blank one of the values in the "code" column then it should be in the c,e,g column which is inline with the value I blanked should be blank

Comment: @PEH , you can see the gif file I uploaded like that's what I mean when I see the value of one in the "code" field that I omit or I deleted then I run the vba code the result is that the output of vba still remains in the column c,e,g

Comment: @Jack well `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B")` is looking for the last used cell in column B. So your code handles only up to that cell, but in column C there is one more row. So you need to change your way how to determine the last row. Do some research there is answers here on how to find the last used cell of multiple columns.

Comment: @PEH , thanks for the reply from you. Is there no other solution so that the problem can be solved?

Comment: @Jack no as it is now the code stops before that row you are talking about. And yes there are always other ways problems can be solved. But you need to decide how you want to fight that problem.